# Unsigned long long serialization in boost

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, uint64

I am compiling a c++ code on a linux ubuntu with g++4.8.1 and boost 1.55.0. 
My program uses a class A, which has a member **table** which is an **unsigned long long array**. The same class has other members which are simple int. I am using boost to serialize my data.
My code work and compile all fine, if I serialize all but the **table** in A.

However it does not compile if I try to serialize **table**. I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::serialization::access::serialize(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = long long unsigned int]’:
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::serialization::access::serialize(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = long long unsigned int]’:
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:69:69:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::serialize(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = long long unsigned int]’
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:128:27:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::serialize_adl(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = long long unsigned int]’
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:152:5:   required from ‘void boost::archive::detail::oserializer<Archive, T>::save_object_data(boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive&, const void*) const [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = long long unsigned int]’
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:101:1:   required from ‘class boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive, long long unsigned int>’
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:214:5:   required from ‘boost::archive::detail::pointer_oserializer<Archive, T>::pointer_oserializer() [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = long long unsigned int]’
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/singleton.hpp:106:7:   [ skipping 95 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:314:44:   required from ‘static void boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<Archive>::invoke(Archive&, T&) [with T = Metapop; Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive]’
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:525:24:   required from ‘void boost::archive::save(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = Metapop]’
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/common_oarchive.hpp:69:40:   required from ‘void boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<Archive>::save_override(T&, int) [with T = Metapop; Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive]’
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oarchive.hpp:80:9:   required from ‘void boost::archive::basic_text_oarchive<Archive>::save_override(T&, int) [with T = Metapop; Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive]’
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:63:9:   required from ‘Archive& boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<Archive>::operator<<(T&) [with T = Metapop; Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive]’ 
simulation.cpp:1403:9:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118:9: error: request for member ‘serialize’ in ‘t’, which is of non-class type ‘long long unsigned int’
     t.serialize(ar, file_version);
     ^
```

I have read aroud that if I used vectors or/and an other data type it would work. However it is critical for me (for speed) to use a raw array of unsigned long long. Any idea ?

Thnaks a lot for you help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serializing `unsigned long long` arrays works for me using gcc 4.7.2 with boost 1.49, gcc 4.2.1 with boost 1.55, and clang 3.4 with boost 1.55:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/version.hpp>

struct Foo {
   unsigned long long bar[3];

   template<class Archive>
   void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int /*version*/) {
      ar & bar;
   }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& foo) {
   return os << foo.bar[0] << ' ' << foo.bar[1] << ' ' << foo.bar[2];
}

int main() {
   std::cout << "Boost version " << BOOST_LIB_VERSION << '\n';

   Foo before;
   before.bar[0] = 0;
   before.bar[1] = 1;
   before.bar[2] = 2;

   std::cout << "before: " << before << '\n';

   std::ostringstream os;
   {
      boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(os);
      oa << before;
   }

   Foo after;
   {
      std::istringstream is(os.str());
      boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(is);
      ia >> after;
   }

   std::cout << "after: " << after << '\n';

   return 0;
}
```

Here's [gcc 4.8 with boost 1.55 on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a292f0216747ab82), also works.

If you are using a pointer to an allocated array, then I think that is your problem. I don't believe you can serialize a bare pointer to a primitive, and I'm sure you can't serialize a bare pointer to an array of primitives because there is no way for serialization to know how many elements a pointer points to.

I would use a `std::vector` over an allocated array because there is no speed disadvantage in doing so. However, if you really want to allocate your own array then you can serialize it with the [`boost::serialization::make_array()` wrapper](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html#arrays) like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>

struct Foo {
   size_t dataSize;
   unsigned long long *data;

   Foo()
      : dataSize(3)
      , data(new unsigned long long[dataSize]) {
   }

   ~Foo() {
      delete[] data;
   }

   // TODO: Production code should disallow default copy constructor
   // and assignment operator.

   template<class Archive>
   void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int /*version*/) {
      ar & dataSize;
      ar & boost::serialization::make_array(data, dataSize);
   }
};

int main() {
   Foo foo;
   foo.data[0] = 0;
   foo.data[1] = 1;
   foo.data[2] = 2;

   boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
   oa << foo;

   return 0;
}
```

It turns out that this question was not about `unsigned long long` at all, but is essentially a duplicate of [boost serialization, deserialization of raw C arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597045/boost-serialization-deserialization-of-raw-c-arrays/20599449#20599449).

Comment: Strange
Does it owrk if you declare:
unsigned long long * bar;
(with the appropriate new /delete)?

Comment: @z_fly_away Oh, you're trying to serialize a bare pointer? That won't work for any kind of allocated array because there is no way for serialization to know the size of the array. I would recommend using a `std::vector` because there is no speed advantage to using an allocated array over a `std::vector`, but I edited my answer above to show how you can use a wrapper around a bare pointer to serialize an allocated array if you really want to.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot. I tested a few comparisons between vectors and arrays and the vector was definitely slower for my use. 
Thanks for the make_array :)